# A Bundle is null after returning back from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I have a problem with a bundle. I have 2 activities(with fragments), and I want to store data in a fragment **FeedListFragment**.

When I rotating screen, it works just fine, but when I returning back from another activity, **the bundle is null**.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    if ( savedInstanceState == null ) {
        feedProviderViewModel.getAll().observe(this, feedProviders -> {
            feedEntryViewModel.deleteAll();
            RssDownloader rssDownloader = new RssDownloader(feedProviders, this, progressBar);
        });
    }

   ...
}
```

And I also have **onSaveInstanceState**

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d("tag","Save instance state called");
    outState.putString(FIRST_RUN,"Downloaded");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use intent to back from your second activity to your first on use onBackPress

```
btn_message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

otherwise you have to put your data into the intent that you have sent already from activity 1

```
btn_message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YOUR ACTIVITY);
        intent.putExtra("bundle",bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

third way to save it on SharedPreference

Comment: Ok, so onSaveInstanceState works only when I rotating screen?

Comment: OnSaveinstance according to document used to save UI states when rotating the device  not saving objects